# Laravel no encuentra archivos en subdirectorios

Tags: laravel

estoy utilizando Laravel 9 alojado en un server xampp en windows, mi problema radica que no me encuentra archivos dentro de subdirectorios en directorios que están en public (Ya tiene el link vinculado), es decir:

```
Public
  -- Imagenes
  |  
  | -- avatares
  |   |   
  |    -- avatar.jpg <<< NO la encuentra
  | --foto.jpg << aqui lo encuentra
```

Si hago esto

`Storage::disk('public')->exists('imagenes/foto.jpg');`

Sí encuentra el archivo, pero:

`Storage::disk('public')->exists('imagenes/avatares/avatar.jpg');`

No lo encuentra, es decir la carpeta avatares no existe para laravel, qué sucede aquí?

De antemano, gracias

Comment: creo que debes de ejecutar el comando `php artisan storage:link` para que se cree dun enlace simbolico en la carpeta public a la carpeta storage, la otra opcion podria ser que la carpeta tiene `I` Mayuscula y en el controlador usas `i` minuscula

Comment: Es un error de tipeo, todos están en minúsculas, y sí, el link está creado, no encuentra esas imagenes dentro de la carpeta avatares dentro de la carpeta imagenes, pero si la imagen está dentro de la carpeta imagenes y no dentro de avatares, laravel sí la encuentra.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la causa, el link simbólico dejó de estar vinculado y tuve que crear de nuevo el `storage:link`, y la otra era que no estaba guardando los archivos en *storage/app/public*, sino en *public*.

Saludos